# "bash -c" doesn't export vars from sourced scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have an inclusion file test.inc:

```
export XXX=xxx
```

I use it when call bash to interpret a string:

```
bash -c ". test.inc; echo $XXX"
```

But the variable is not set at the point of echo command. If I do 'export' I can see it though:

```
bash -c ". test.inc; export"
```

Shows

```
declare -x XXX="XXX"
```

How do I make my first command see the exported variables from sourced files when I use bash -c syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using double quotes. Therefore your current shell expands `$XXX` long before the `bash -c` instance sees it. Switch to single quotes, or escape the dollar sign.